# Rotating/moving objects on a UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, ios4, rotation

I need to rotate and move objects on a UIView when the orientation changes. To that end I have the following in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation`

```
if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation)) {
    [self repositionObjectAfterRotation:scrollView x:0 y:100 width:480 height:150];
    [self repositionObjectAfterRotation:pageControl x:50 y:430 width:100 height:30];    
}
```

My `repositionObjectAfterRotation:x:y:width:height:` looks like this, which takes the object and alters its bounds, before setting the new bounds.

```
- (void)repositionObjectAfterRotation:(UIView *)anObject x:(int)x y:(int)y 
                                     width:(int)width height:(int)height
{   

    [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
        CGRect boundsRect = anObject.bounds;
        boundsRect.origin.x = x;
        boundsRect.origin.y = y;
        boundsRect.size.width = width;
        boundsRect.size.height = height;
        anObject.bounds = boundsRect;
    } completion:^ (BOOL finished){
        if (finished) {
            [UIView animateWithDuration:kAnimationDuration animations:^{
                anObject.alpha = 1.0;
            }];
        }
    }];

}
```

When the view rotates back to portrait, it only displays half of the scrollview, even though my NSLogs state that the frame & bounds are correct...

Am I rotating / repositioning objects correctly or is there an easier/preferred way to support landscape?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting the height to "150" when you rotate to Landscape, but don't adjust it back when you go back to portrait.

I don't know how your auto-sizing is set-up in IB, so I can't state how these objects will resize/move when left by themselves.

Comment: Sorry it does move back in portrait, copy and paste error. My bad. In IB all the struts and springs are selected.

Answer (score 0):

3 points:

1. you don't need to explicitly begin an animation, system will do it anyway (unless your animation is "different from rotation."
2. I think overriding `layoutSubviews` is more convenient. It's called after each rotation, and `[device orientation]` gives you the new orientation.
3. You probably want to change the `frame` of these views, not their `bounds`, which is an internal value (i.e. it matters only "inside" that view).

`frame` says 'put me in this position of the superivew', which is what you want. `bound` defines the coordinate your, say, scrollView uses for its subviews. what you need here is the frame.

In `layoutSubviews`, just change the frame, the animation you want will apply automatically:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation])) {
        anObject.frame = landscapeFrame;
    }
    else {
        anObject.frame = portraitFrame;
    }
}
```

Comment: The `frame` is in relation to the superview coordinates isn't it? Overriding layoutSubviews is something i have never done before. Do I just override `layoutSubviews` and put my movement code there? Nothing special? I want to animate because my items dont just rotate i.e. i have a scrollview which needs to more from 0,80 to 0,100 when rotated.

Comment: `layoutSubviews` is not called when the view rotates... I tried calling `[self.view setNeedsLayout];` in `willRotateToIntefaceOrientation` but it still didnt enter my method

Comment: hmm... I'm using this method daily... and in the worst case `layoutSubviews` should be invoked when `setNeedsLayout` is called. I assume you've checked `layoutSubviews` is properly implemented in your view?